# How to make github shows same commit dates?

Tags: github

I have completed my project on 20-10-22 and made a commit using `git commit -m "finished"` . But when I pushed the code to github it shows todays date ? How can I make github show the original date ie 20-10-22 ?

Answer (score 0):

When you commit something on GitHub, it shows the date that you commited it on...

I don't think you can change it to something else.